# Symfony fullcalendar delete event by id

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, controller, fullcalendar

Im trying to delete an event based on his id, I get the id but the controller gives an error because it expected an object and a string was given.

---

The data of a modal gets filled on event click.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;      
    //filling data          
        $('#ev_title').html(eventObj.title);    
        $('#ev_start').html('<b>Fecha inicio: </b> ' + eventObj.start);
        $('#ev_end').html('<b>Fecha fin: </b> ' + eventObj.end);
        $('#ev_desc').html('<b>Descripcion: </b>' + 
        eventObj.extendedProps.description);
        $('#ev_mail').html('<b>Correo destino: </b> ' + 
        eventObj.extendedProps.mail);
        $('#ev_id').html(eventObj.id);},
```

---

A button redirects to delete function.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="z-index: 9999;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">         

            <h4 id="ev_title" class="modal-title"></h4> 
        --> <h4 id="ev_id" class="modal-title"></h4> 

        </div>
        <!-- dialog body -->
        <div class="modal-body">                

        <p id="ev_start" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_end" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_mail" class="modal-body"></p>
        <p id="ev_desc" class="modal-body"></p>            

        </div>
        <!-- dialog buttons -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="borrar()">Borrar evento</button>      
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
function borrar(){              
            var data = $('#ev_id').html();              

    $.ajax({                
        type: "POST",           
        data: { id: data },
        url: "{{ path('borrar') }}", 

    function(response){ 
    if(response.code === 200 && response.success){ alert('success!'); } 
    else{ alert('something broken');}},

        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data);
            alert('OK');
        } 
    });         
}
```

[XHR POST ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4qV7.png)

---

Controller:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request){ 

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$data = $request->request->get('id');

$em->remove($data);
$em->flush();
```

---

This is the error message:

> EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, string given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the object from the id and remove the object.
`$object = $em->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Entity::class)->find($request->get("id")` and then remove $object as you did :
`$em->remove($object); $em->flush();`

Tips : if you’re using Symfony >=3.4 with default services configuration you can inject `EntityManagerInterface $em, ClassRepository $repo` in the parameters of your function.

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, ClassRepository $repo){ 
$object = $repo->find($request->get('id');
$em->remove($object);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I couldnt add $em and $repo to the parameters of the function but I used them inside and it worked.  Thank you                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
public function deleteAction(Request $request){ 
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$object = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:Evento')->find($request->get('id'));
$em->remove($object);
$em->flush();

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are plenty ways to implement that, but the best and easiest practice is to embed the id inside the url like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}")
 */
```

then use Symfony's [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) to get the object like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}")
 */
public function deleteAction(YourClass $yourClassObject, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $em->remove($object);
    $em->flush();
}
```